# JS merge sort function runs out of memory

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I was trying to improve the time of a typical merge-sort function using pop().  When I run it in Chrome, it crashes with memory errors. Obviously this means that it's looping without completing, but I can't tell why.

Here's the code:

```
function mergeSorted(a, b){
  var c = [];
  while(a.length && b.length){
    var a1 = a.pop();
    var b1 = b.pop();
    var aIndex = parseInt((a.length) - 1);
    var bIndex = parseInt((b.length) - 1);
    while(b[bIndex] >= a[aIndex]) c.push(b1);
    while(a[aIndex] >= b[bIndex]) c.push(a1);
  }
  return c;
}

var a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9];
var b = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
mergeSorted(a, b);
```

Comment: Debug, breakpoints, step over.

Comment: Nothing ever changes `aIndex` or `bIndex` in those inner `while` loops.

Comment: `while(b[bIndex] >= a[aIndex]) c.push(b1);` that will loop. You modify `c` but condition is about `a` and `b`

Comment: Also, you don't need `parseInt` as you _will_ get back an int from the computed length property. If you would use `parseInt`, at least pass it the decimal value so it converts correctly: `parseInt(length, 10)`

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. Andrey, I knew where it was breaking but I couldn't tell why.

Comment: Also, an earlier version of this I wrote made me think that putting the pop() in the while loops was decreasing the length of the array each time, @Michael Laffargue.

Comment: @somethinghere, I forgot to take out the parseInt from something I was testing earlier.  I was getting back a number value when checking the index variable, but also an undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last two `while` loops should be `if` conditions, since you don't change any of the `while` loop conditions internally in the loop, so will loop indefinitely.

```
if(b[bIndex] >= a[aIndex]) c.push(b1);
if(a[aIndex] >= b[bIndex]) c.push(a1);
```